# ¿Como transpilar archivos ES6 a ES5 con Babel?

Tags: javascript, babeljs

Estoy tratando de seguir una serie de ejemplos para aprender ES6, pero no logro conseguir que transpile d forma correcta.

En mi caso utilizo la siguiente linea para hacerlo

```
babel --watch index.js --out-file index_ES5.js
```

Mi archivo `.eslintrc` tiene la siguiente configuración

```
{
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "plugins": ["import"],
  "extends": "airbnb",
  "env": {
    "node": true,
    "es6": true,
    "browser": true
  },
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 6,
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": false
    }
  },
  "rules": {
    // evita que marque error al usar console
    "no-console": 0,
    // permite usar variables con _
    "no-underscore-dangle": 0,
    // máximo de línea: 99
    "max-len": [1, 99, 2],
    // obliga a usar punto y coma
    "semi": [1, "always"],
    // obliga a usar const sobre let
    "prefer-const": 2,
    // obliga a definir llaves en if/else
    "curly": [2, "all"],
    // prefiere === a ==
    "eqeqeq": [2, "allow-null"],
    "no-shadow": 1,
    // no exige que las funciones como callbacks
    // tengan un nombre
    "func-names": 0,
    // prefiere apóstrofe a comillas
    // y también para template literal
    "quotes": [
      2,
      "single",
      {
        "allowTemplateLiterals": true
      }
    ],
    // previene múltiples líneas en blanco
    "no-multiple-empty-lines": [ 2, {
      "max": 1,
      "maxEOF": 0,
      "maxBOF": 0
    }],
    // no activa el warning en parámetros rest
    "no-unused-vars": ["warn", {
      "ignoreRestSiblings": true
    }],
    "linebreak-style": "off"
  },
  "settings": {
    "node": {
      "extensions": [
        ".js"
      ],
      "moduleDirectory": [
        "node_modules",
        "./"
      ]
    },
    "import/resolver": {
      "node": {
        "extensions": [
          ".js"
        ],
        "moduleDirectory": [
          "node_modules",
          "./"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para compilar `ES6` a `ES5` necesitas instalar un [`preset`](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/#presets), puntualmente:

- Instalar [`babel-preset-es2015`](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-es2015/), por ejemplo, vía `npm`:

  ```
  $ npm install babel-preset-es2015 –save-dev
  ```
- Luego puedes usarlo:

  - Vía `CLI`

    ```
    $ babel --watch index.js --presets es2015 --out-file index_ES5.js
    ```
  - Vía [`.babelrc`](http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babelrc/):
    Debes crear un archivo de nombre `.babelrc` y que contenga:

    ```
    {
      "presets": ["es2015"]
    }
    ```

    Siendo este último el mas recomendado, ya que te evitaría tener que indicar el `presets` cada vez que ejecutes `babel`

**PD**: El archivo `.eslintrc` es para el [`ESLint`](https://eslint.org/) (*corrector y resaltador de errores de sintaxis*).

Comment: ya instalo y te comento, disculpa, asumo que el nombre del archivo seria `.babelrc`

Comment: @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales, he actualizado mi respuesta, para aclarar lo que comentas.

Comment: Gracias, ahora si transpilo de forma correcta.